# Run git pull from non-web directory, storing files into web directory

Tags: git, github

I have a git repo that lives outside of the web directory on my development server. I have this set to pull from a development branch of the repo on GitHub. That seems to work fine. However, the problem is that if I run `git pull`, it pulls the files into the *current* directory, but I want it to pull into a web-accessible directory.

I have the following in my config file, but it seems to be ignored:

```
[core]
    bare = false
    worktree = /path/to/www/RepoDirectory
```

If I run a clone command such as:

```
git --work-tree=../relative/path/to/www/RepoDirectory clone -b DevBranch git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git
```

it'll clone into the web directory, which is what I want. But a `git pull` will pull into the repo directory.

I also tried

```
git --work-tree=../relative/path/to/www/RepoDirectory pull
```

but that results in:

> fatal: git-pull cannot be used without a working tree

I'm new to GitHub, and have been reading the dozens of SO posts that all seem very similar to my question, but none of the solutions work. My host installed git on our server for me the other day, version 1.7.1. Do I need it upgraded or something?

Comment: After you clone into `/path/to/www` you will have a `path/to/www/topdir`. This top level work tree directory is the path name you must specify with `--work-tree=` or similar, not just `/path/to/www`. (Relative paths should work as you expect,)

Comment: After the clone, the only subdirectories it created were the ones in the repo. To be more specific, my initial clone was `git --work-tree=../path/to/www/RepoDirectory clone -b DevBranch ...`. So RepoDirectory does have some new subdirectories, but just the ones the repo created. I'm not sure what `topdir` is? I'm trying to do the pulls using roughly the same command as the clone, just replacing the word `clone` with `pull`, and it still generates the error.

Comment: Don't mix deployment with source control. Let the Git repo be outside the web directory and write a simple script that runs `git pull` then uses `rsync` to copy the needed files from the repo to the web directory.

Comment: Thanks @axiac I didn't think of `rsync`. That being said though, I'm kind of surprised that this is the best way to do it. It seems wasteful to pull the repo into a directory that I'm never going to use it in (being that I'm just going to `rsync` the contents to the intended directory).

Comment: Ah, my first comment wasn't quite right: `git --work-tree=... clone` is a rather odd operation. But I agree with axiac here, Git makes a poor deployment tool (it can be used as one, just as a hammer can be used as a screwdriver and a wrench can be used as a hammer...).

Comment: Thanks @torek - I found that `--work-tree` business on another SO question, I can't remember which. It worked, but if the subsequent pulls don't work then it defeats the purpose. I just did a normal clone into the non-web directory. I agree with you both - it would be nice if git could pull into the web directory but it seems like a lot more trouble than it's worth. I'll just pull to non-web and `rsync` to web